How to install libtinfo5 on Ubuntu24.04
Please help me for installing libtinfo5 into 24.04.1 LTS.
I almost build a program for AWE in Ubuntu 22.04.2 LTS but a new version Ubuntu 24.04.1 LTS \n \l suddenly encountered (I installed with no doubt) without libtinfo5. Then my work stopped suddenly.
Your help would be much appreciated if you could please let me know any information on the installation of libtinfo5 into the new version Ubuntu 24.04.1 LTS.

If you're building the program, why are you trying to build or use an unsupported library that stopped being security & other patched back on 1 July 2023 ?  I'd amend your program to use the supported version (6)

To install libtinfo5 in Ubuntu 24.04 open the terminal and type:
sudo apt update
wget http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/universe/n/ncurses/libtinfo5_6.3-2ubuntu0.1_amd64.deb
sudo apt install ./libtinfo5_6.3-2ubuntu0.1_amd64.deb


After some trial including "sudo apt install libtinfo.so.5", the program "optimized_dp" has  worked.  Thank you Karel,  for your kind help.
